# Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change

Tags: workflow

I am not able to understand the criteria how this works..and what will happen if we doesnot choose that.

Answer (score 4):

[If rule is enabled to re-evaluate, Salesforce re-evaluates all workflow rules on the object.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_updates_reevalute_wf.htm&language=en)

Lets assume that you have two rules on contact:

Rule 1: if Department is updated to '123', change Department to contact.id

Rule 2: if Title is updated to 'VP', change Department to '123'.

In case when rule 2 is not set to re-evaluate. And you change Title to VP, workflow will update department to '123' only.

But if rule 2 is set to re-evaluate rules. And you change Title to VP, rule2 will change Department to '123', which will fire rule1 and Department will be changed to Id

Answer (score 0):

This is easy: let's say you have a workflow WF1 that has Stage field set to 'Closed'. And also have another workflow WF2 that has criteria like `Stage = 'Closed'` and does something else (like email notification). When you have the flag `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` checked on field update from WF1, WF2 criteria will return true and this will trigger email notification, and this will not happen when you have the flag unchecked.

Usually you won't have many field updates that have to trigger workflows, but you also have to remember to have this flag checked when you have one :)

Answer (score -2):

If the workflow rule criteria is only
(1)created,
(2)created, and every time it's edited.....then only re-evaluate will work.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Am sorry but I am flagging this answer as it is very low quality, and it isn't a value-add considering there are other better quality answers available.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that this should be deleted just because of the quality. I think downvoting is probably the better tool here. Sajal, please take some time to read [How to Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help]. Sites like this one _thrive_ on accurate answers with plenty of details. In my mind, a good answer will contain _what_ OP's (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) problem is, _why_ it is a problem, _how_ to fix the issue, and _why_ the fix works. That template doesn't fit 100% here, but the point is that I'd like to see more effort from you.